# Cannot get redirected back to App from Angel.co API call in Android App

Tags: android, oauth

I have an app that authenticates a user through the following call:

```
https://angel.co/api/oauth/authorize?
client_id=...&
state=...&
response_type=code
```

I have setup the following code to authenticate and then grab the code for the AccessToken:

```
mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("https://angel.co/api/oauth/authorize?"
                              + "client_id=" + clientId + "&"
                              + "response_type=" + RESPONSE_TYPE)
            );
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

This is my manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.UserLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp"
                android:scheme="dezign.scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It launches to Chrome browser fine from the app when I click the `mLoginButton` however when it is done and hits the `redirectUri` it shows the following error and does go back to the app:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? So far I haven't found an acceptable answer on SO.

**UPDATE SEEMED TO HAVE SOLVED THE ISSUE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now!

I had the scheme and host wrong, for more documentation on this please check out the following link here:

[More about implicit intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ires)

My host and scheme were backwards, it should look like this:

[image]

For my app specifically it should be:

```
android:scheme="myapp"
android:host="dezign.scheme"
```